# Not sure which Ubuntu to install (64 or 32 bit)

Tags: upgrade

I want to use Ubuntu. I have Win 7 Home Premium 32-bit right now... I used to have 64 on this laptop (Toshiba Satellite c650) but my disc got a ring of death.

Intel Penium CPU B940 2.00GHz, 4GB RAM

Also, I'm guessing I need an image mounter such as PowerISO to install Ubuntu, if I don't have a DVD lying around that I can mount to?
I'm a noob. Thanks for your help, in advance.

EDIT: My question wasn't clear... can my processor and RAM handle 64-bit Ubuntu? Hell of a lot nicer than Win7

Answer (score 0):

[Your processor](http://ark.intel.com/products/55626/Intel-Pentium-Processor-B940-(2M-Cache-2_00-GHz)) can certainly handle 64-bit software. RAM shouldn't be a problem either, but I've been wrong before.

You can find instructions on creating a [bootable USB stick](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) if you don't have a DVD burner and spare DVD sitting around.